# Rails and Git, which branch is being used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, github

This is probably a newb question, but I'll ask anyways.  For the longest time I've worked on different apps in a git master branch.  Now I'm to the point where I want to test features by creating a different branch instead of working on the master branch.

I'm comfortable with creating and merging branches but my question is this:

I'm running Anvil/Pow to serve up the codebase in my git repo.  It serves up the directory "appname" or what have you.  If I switch to a new branch, i.e. "feature", does Anvil/Pow/Rails server automatically know I'm working with that branch or do I have to do something specific to tell the server to use that branch in my development environment.

Again, probably a newb question but I'm just now starting to really use branching and wanted to know how the magic works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pow.cx](http://pow.cx/) simply serves what it finds in the project directory symlinked into ~/.pow/ (see the install notes or the quick screencast on the homepage). Whatever files exist there are served.

When you check out a different branch, the files may change, and those changes should be picked up by pow. Just so I'm absolutely crystal clear, *pow doesn't understand git. It simply serves what it sees*.

Does that make things clear?

Ps: you could test that yourself, by switching between branches and loading/viewing, using your Anvil setup, some part of the project that changes.

Comment: About your question on how git branch magic works, you should check out this page :

http://onlywei.github.io/explain-git-with-d3/

Whenever you do a git commit on that page, it behaves as if there is new material to be committed. So just imagine that the part where you make changes in the codebase is being automagically done for you. The goal, however, is to understand how branches work. So choose *git branch* under basic commands on the page and branch, commit, commit, checkout some other branch, commit there, make another branch, and so on... till you get the answer to your question :)

Comment: This makes sense, thanks for the explanation.  I figured that's how it worked, but was curious if there was something specific I needed to do.  I'll make a branch and start testing some changes on it to see how it serves up.

Comment: Thanks.. You just helped me get closer to the 50 reputation needed in order to make comments :D